# Ecommerce front end web application for selling cloud services based on vmware

Tags: .net, e-commerce, cloud, vmware

I am looking for an extendible ecommerce package/server to sell cloud computing services based on vmware and I am wondering if this community has comments to share.

Basically the potential customer should be able to order a virtual machine online by choosing number of cpus, amount of RAM and storage. The ideal software would support vmware such that when the customer orders a vm through the ecommerce web app, all the provisioning tasks are triggered by the ecommerce software on vmware. So the customer will have the vm up and running after all provisioning tasks are finished.

**Does anyone have any experience or any suggestion for ecommerce package/server that can sell services like cloud computing?**